# Why does my content column extend under the footer?

Tags: bootstrap-5

My site layout is made with an header navbar, a simple footer (both fixed-top/bottom) and 3 different columns, that should be independent and at least one (the left one) scrollable.

I have resolved (or at least I suppose to) most of the problems, but the scrollable column go under the footer and i cannot see all the text.

Here (for who don't know erb) the parts with render and yield will copy partial html code. I don't think it is relevant all the html. Just know that "calendarbar" is a text long enough to activate scrolling.

I've tried also to use alternative padding to body, with similar result:

```
body {
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}
```

Logic tell me this should be correct, but the column don't stop on the footer, and text go under it. I don't understand what is wrong. Thanks for the help!

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
      <%= render "header"%>
    </header>
    
    <div class="row vh-100">
      <div class="col-md-2 vh-100 overflow-y-scroll">
        <%= render "calendarbar"%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 vh-100 overflow-y-hidden">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 vh-100 border overflow-y-scroll">
        <%= render "messengerbar"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
      <%= render "footer"%>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please update the demo above to show the problem. Background color classes could help us visualize.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution "bootstrap style".

My solution is to remove all fixed top/bottom elements from header and footer, and use row and flex utilities for "fix" the positions. Key element is flex-grow-1 that "impose" the column to fill all the space and block the footer as is fixed bottom.

```
<body class="overflow-hidden">
    <div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 p-0 m-0">
              <%= render "header"%>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-grow-1" style="min-height:0">
          <div class="col-2 border m-0 h-100 d-flex flex-column">
              <%= render "calendarbar"%>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 border h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center" >
              <%= yield %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 border m-0 h-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <%= render "messengerbar"%>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 border p-0 m-0"> 
            <%= render "footer"%>
           </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```